# Wtforms- writing fieldlist data into mysql

Tags: mysql, for-loop, flask-wtforms, fieldlist

Suppose I have a form like so:

```
Toys= FieldList(TextField('what toys do you have?'),min_entries=5)
Fruits= FieldList(TextField('what fruits do you have?'),min_entries=5)
Jewelry= FieldList(TextField('what jewelries do you have?'),min_entries=5)
Candy= FieldList(TextField('what candies do you have?'),min_entries=5)
```

without explicitly defining the submitted values like
`Toy1=form.Toys[1].data`, how might I aggregate all the FieldList data in a form submission for writing into a SQL table like so:?

```
Toys | Fruits | Jewelry | Candy
ball  apple    Necklace  M&Ms
stick orange   Bracelet  skittles
top   grapes   tie clip  lollipop
```

For the sake of simplicity, I've set `min_entries=5` for all fields. I tried using a for loop to append column names and values into a dictionary and writing it into my database like so:

```
field_dict=dict()
    for f in form:
        if str(f.type) in ['FieldList']:
            for x in range(1,5):
                field_dict.update({f.name:f.data[x]})
                    sql_insert="INSERT INTO tablename ({}) values ({})".format(
                        ",".join(field_dict.keys()),
                        ",".join('"' + str(value) + '"' for value in field_dict.values()))
                    c.execute(sql_insert)
```

However, it's writing into the database everytime it encounters a `Fieldlist`, resulting in a table like:

```
 Toys | Fruits | Jewelry | Candy
ball   NULL       NULL     NULL
ball   apple      NULL     NULL
ball   apple     Necklace  NULL
ball   apple     Necklace  M&Ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My reading of the question is that you have a list of entries from your form you want to combine into a tuple and insert into the database..

To save me some typing lets say you have:

```
# some list of keys obtained or hard coded as global..
KEYS = ['Toys', 'Fruits', 'Candy']

# and a form in which you have
Toys= FieldList(TextField('what toys do you have?'),min_entries=3)
Fruits= FieldList(TextField('what fruits do you have?'),min_entries=3)
Candy= FieldList(TextField('what candies do you have?'),min_entries=3)
```

Now your job is to cycle the form and package up a tuple:

```
form = Form()
for _i in range(3):
    tup = ()
    for key in KEYS:
        tup += (getattr(form, key)[_i].data,)
    sql = "INSERT INTO tablename ({}) values {}".format(
              ",".join(KEYS), str(tup))
    c.execute(sql)
```

Give it (or some debugged derivative!) a try